# elasticsearch node heap size and the file system buffer cache

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a physical machine with 128Gb of RAM. I am running three elasticsearch nodes on this particular machine. Each elasticsearch node has 30gb ES_HEAP_SIZE. Each index has 5 primaries and 5 replicas i.e total of 10 active shards per index. Currently there are 3200 active shards in the cluster of three nodes. 
When I do a query on all the indices I get a lot of shard failed exceptions. I think it is because there is no space to search on 320 indices at a time in the RAM.
My question is how does elasticsearch make use of the file system cache of the operating system and how does it make use of the heap size allocated to it. 
My appilcation is indexing intensive rather than search intensive. So I do not care about filter caching. So am I over allocating the heap size?
Can anyone explain me how does elasticsearch uses the heap size and file system cache so that I can architecture my elasticsearch cluster accrodingly ?